# Search and Dynamic Content

Tags: web-part, search, content, crawl

I have content that is stored in lists in SharePoint 2010. A webpart located on a page, depending on a users location, will pull content specific content from that list and display it on the page. I have several pages like this.

When I do a search on a page, I do not have lists displayed, so my search is empty. Is it possible to somehow get the webpages with the dynamic content to show up upon search?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Updated post - SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this without custom code in 2010. You might be able to do it in 2013 with a combination of Query Rules and Display Templates, but in 2010 you don't have the User property features out of the box.

Comment: I can write custom code, I am just not sure where to start, or any idea on how to do this, if you have any suggestions

Comment: You'd have to cobble together an additional search web part that applies an additional user query to a Core Search Results web part, passing the user context. This is easier in 2013.